# How to enable downloads (count) icon on app page in google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

In this image i marked download notification displayed part in play store

[image]

i upload apk in playstore. it's everything working fine but download notification not displayed . how to display download notification?

Answer (score 1):

It will take time to if you just uploaded the application. Once you have a few downloads it will start showing automatically. You do not need to do anything for that to show up.

Comment: Few  download means how much? any minimum installation. google pay my app download count near 80

Comment: when did it go live?

Comment: few month before but mostly two days wise i have upload new modified version

Comment: share the link to your app page

Comment: I think it only shows up with an amount of downloads that is worth showing off, like thousands.